# Check if powershell string contains an asterisk

Tags: powershell

I have a string : `$row.TableName_Org[$i]`
The value it contains is

```
This is a happy little asterisk: '*'
```

Now I want to do an IF based on the fact that the string contains an asterisk.

```
    if($row.TableName_Org[$i] -Match "*") {
    //Do Something
    }
```

However gives me this error:

```
"*" - Kwantiteitsmeter {x,y} wordt door niets voorafgegaan. parseren       
At C:\Users\hveijer\VS Code Repos\migratie-uitwissel\ReadData.ps1:33 char:4
+    $row.TableName_Org[$i] -match "*"
+    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (:) [], ArgumentException  
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.ArgumentException
```

Comment: The asterisk is a special charachter for regex. If you want to match some of those charachters you have to escape it ... like this: `-match '\*'`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you've found out yourself, the escape character in PowerShells wildcard/glob mechanism is `` ` `` (backtick):

```
'string with * in it' -like '`*'
```

... but the backtick is also the escape character for expandable (double-quoted) strings, leading to situations with awkward double escaping, like:

```
$pattern = "${prefix}``*"
```

For this reason, I prefer to let PowerShell escape my search terms for me instead of doing it manually:

```
[wildcardpattern]::Escape("${prefix}*")
```

Answer (score 1):

Turns out I had to escape the `*` using ` (slash backtick)